# What is the appropriate research design for this?

Tags: experiment-design

I am doing a research on the effectiveness of multimedia instruction to classroom performance of students vs traditional approach. This is my plan but I am not sure what is the name of this research design that I'll be using:

I have two groups: One group to receive traditional teaching approach while another one will be receiving a multimedia-based instruction in a certain period. Pretest will be conducted at first and a post test after the intervention period. No other variables are included in the study.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretest posttest design. This is not a very good design, especially for measures that are not very reliable (which would include any measure of the effectiveness of instruction).  Much better to have more time points.  You also should think about randomization (which you don't mention).

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Peter! I appreciate your reply. :) Please enlighten me more on what should I do to make my study better.

Comment: Like I said, measure them at several time points, not just two.